# Python module "twill"--HTML flood during variable assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment, twill

I'm making a simple command line program for gathering and parsing information from websites (pretty generic) using the Twill module in Python.  I want to assign the HTML output to a variable using Twill's show() command to run the page through my parsing commands, but every time I assign it to a variable...

```
htmlString = twill.commands.show()
```

I get a humongous flood of HTML on to the command line (and IDLE, for that matter).  Why is this?  I'm not asking to print the variable, there's no print command anywhere near it.  I just want to assign in for further manipulation.  Why would a variable assignment cause a print to occur?  It's not a fatal error or anything, just really, really inconvenient.  I'm on Python 2.6, Twill 0.9, and Ubuntu, if that pertains to anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to parse HTML, never faced `twill`. But I see you calling `.show()` method, maybe this method have `print` statement inside.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure show() does have a print command built in.  I guess that causes it to print off to the shell even during variable assignment.  Would there be any way to inhibit the print, aside from modifying Twill itself?

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way!  Can't believe I got an answer, let alone so quickly!

Comment: You can capture command output by passing any write-enabled file handle to twill.set_output, e.g. `twill.set_output(StringIO())` will send all non-error output into a StringIO() object.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks again.  If anyone else has to deal with this problem...I found out there's also a "browser" submodule in Twill where show() derives from, it's another layer in Twill's wrapping that provides slightly lower level functions (they aren't documented on the website).

Answer (score 1):

Twill is an odd one and prints a lot of output to the terminal. It's not the variable assignment that's causing the stuff to be printed out, it's the `show()` method. It will print (rather than return) the output.